# URL Parameter Express IN Keyword

Tags: javascript, express, url-parameters

How do I mimmic the SQL Keyword IN in an URL Querystring? I am able to narrow my results by simple querys like:
`http://localhost:3000/data?color=blue`
However, how do I pass in a query string if I wanted colors blue and green, without repeating the "&color=" part over and over.

Comment: Make another cell with color id or anything else and pass that as string?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you want to pass the query string like this:

```
?colors=blue,green,yellow
```

This system is used for example in the Google Maps Places API to restrict the required fields, but there is no standard way of doing it.

However, keep in mind that the URL cannot be infinite long (depends on the browser, but depending on the database, IN can usually not be filled with infinite values either). If you want to pass huge datasets, consider switching to HTTP POST and sending the values in the body.

Comment: Of course this is working. Google uses it for example in the widely used Maps Places API to specify a list of required fields.